# Vertical alignment to the top of the cell in longtable

Tags: longtable, alignment, vertical

I went through many of advices here, but I still have problem with the alignment of my longtable.
I have this longtable:

```latex
\begin{flushleft} 
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{10cm} l@{}}

30 \% akrylamidový roztok                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}29,2 \% akrylamid (w/v) \\ 0,8 \% bis-akrylamid (w/v)\end{tabular}                                                                                                                    \\
10x koncentrovaný elektroforetický pufer                                                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0,25 M Tris \\ 0,192 M Gly \\ 35 mM SDS (0,01 \%, w/v)\end{tabular}                                                                                                                   \\
Lyzačný vzorkový pufer                                                                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}62,5 mM Tris/HCl (pH 6,8)\\  2 \% SDS (w/v)\\ 10 \% glycerol (v/v)\\ 0,01 \% BF modrá (w/v)\\ 0,1 M DTT (w/v)\\ 50 mM NaF\\ 1 mM Na3VO4 \\ 0,5 \% PIC (v/v)\end{tabular} \\
transferový pufer na SDS-PAGE                                                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}20 mM Tris\\ 189 mM Gly \\ 0,1 \% SDS (w/v) \\ 10 \% methanol (v/v)\end{tabular}                                                                                                      \\
Tris pufer na separačný polyakrylamidový gél    & 1,5 M Tris/HCl (pH 8,8)                                                                                                                                                                                          \\
Tris pufer na zaostrovací polyakrylamidový gél & 1 M Tris/HCl (pH 6,8)                                                                                                                                                                                            \\
T-TBS pufer                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}20 mM Tris/HCl (pH 7,5)\\ 140 mM NaCl\\ 0,1 \% Tween® 20 (v/v)\end{tabular}                                                                                                           \\
Väzobný pufer (HBB z angl. HEPES binding buffer) & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}100 mM HEPES\\ 100 mM NaCl\\ 5 mM KCl\\ 1,3 mM MgSO4 \\ 1 mM EDTA\\ 10 mM Glc\\ 15 mM NaOAc\\ 1\% BSA (w/w)\\ pH 7,6\end{tabular}                                                    
\end{longtable}
\end{flushleft}
```

And the text in the first column is still aligned in the middle of the cell and I want it to be at the top of the cell. How can I do that, please?
[image: this is how i want it to look]

Comment: If you don't want the `tabular` environments vertically centered to the current baseline, you should no use option `[c]`. See a LaTeX introduction for more information to the optional argument of `tabular`. BTW: IMHO the inner `tabular` does not really make sense. But without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) I cannot really test your code.

Comment: BTW: The `flushleft` environment also does not make sense. `longtable` supports an optional argument for the horizontal alignment of the table. See section 5 of the [`longtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but why not like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft} 
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{10cm} l@{}}

30 \% akrylamidový roztok                      & 29,2 \% akrylamid (w/v) \\ 
                                               & 0,8 \% bis-akrylamid (w/v) \\
10x koncentrovaný elektroforetický pufer       & 0,25 M Tris \\ 
                                               & 0,192 M Gly \\ 
                                               & 35 mM SDS (0,01 \%, w/v) \\
Lyzačný vzorkový pufer                         & 62,5 mM Tris/HCl (pH 6,8)\\  
                                               & 2 \% SDS (w/v)\\ 
                                               & 10 \% glycerol (v/v)\\ 
                                               & 0,01 \% BF modrá (w/v)\\ 
                                               & 0,1 M DTT (w/v)\\ 
                                               & 50 mM NaF\\ 
                                               & 1 mM Na3VO4 \\ 
                                               & 0,5 \% PIC (v/v) \\
transferový pufer na SDS-PAGE                  & 20 mM Tris\\ 
                                               & 189 mM Gly \\ 
                                               & 0,1 \% SDS (w/v) \\ 
                                               & 10 \% methanol (v/v) \\
Tris pufer na separačný polyakrylamidový gél   & 1,5 M Tris/HCl (pH 8,8) \\
Tris pufer na zaostrovací polyakrylamidový gél & 1 M Tris/HCl (pH 6,8) \\
T-TBS pufer                                    & 20 mM Tris/HCl (pH 7,5)\\ 
                                               & 140 mM NaCl\\ 
                                               & 0,1 \% Tween® 20 (v/v) \\
Väzobný pufer (HBB z angl. HEPES binding buffer) & 100 mM HEPES\\
                                               & 100 mM NaCl\\
                                               & 5 mM KCl\\
                                               & 1,3 mM MgSO4 \\
                                               & 1 mM EDTA\\
                                               &  10 mM Glc\\
                                               & 15 mM NaOAc\\
                                               & 1\% BSA (w/w)\\
                                               & pH 7,6
\end{longtable}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted! Thank You.. I don't know why I did it in so complicated way :D